# Cast Nhibernate parent entity to child

Tags: c#, nhibernate, inheritance, casting

Parent

```
public class ParentMap : Map<Parent>
    {
        public ParentMap()
        {
            DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn<string>("Provider").Nullable();
        }
    }
```

Children:

```
public class Child1Map : SubclassMap<Child1>
{
    public FacebookAccountMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("child1");
    }
}
public class Child2Map : SubclassMap<Child2>
{
    public FacebookAccountMap()
    {
        DiscriminatorValue("child2");
    }
}
```

from service i get instance of `Parent` but with property `item.Provider` equal to *childOne*, how can i get instance of `Child1` or `Child2` based **on value of proprty Provider** ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NHibernate Inheritance - Discriminator-Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664936/nhibernate-inheritance-discriminator-value)

Comment: i dont need any defaults, i want to be allowed to force change discriminator, even if any class DOES NOT support this one

Comment: I don't understand your use of English, but I deleted the answer so that others will still look at the question. Maybe someone else will understand better than I.

Answer (score 0):

Your question I'm afraid isn't completely clear, but I'm going to take a guess:

Most likely you don't receive instances of Parent, but instances of ParentProxy, a class that NHibernate generates that inherit from Parent. This class cannot be cast to Child1, but the instance will in fact *contain* an instance of the Child1 class. Methods calls are forwarded to this contained class. This mechanism is part of NHibernate's lazy load system - since NHibernate needs to create the proxy object without loading the full object data, it doesn't know which exact type to use.

This scenario will happen if you get the instance by following a reference from some other class.

The idea is normally that:

1. You normally shouldn't need to cast. If you need to cast from base class to subclass you haven't succeeded in creating a good object oriented design and you should explore methods to avoid the cast (since the inheritance structure implies that the caller shouldn't need to care about the actual subclass, the need to cast violates this principle and should therefore be avoided when possible).
2. If you really must access the true Child1 instance, you could [provide an `As<T>()` method in the base class](http://sessionfactory.blogspot.se/2010/08/hacking-lazy-loaded-inheritance.html).